# Excepción no manejada dentro de un Try/Catch

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy tratando de comparar dos archivos XML usando una librería llamada XmlDiffLib que se encuentra en el siguiente link:
https://github.com/BrutalSimplicity/XmlDiffLib

Mi código es este:

```
private void Compare(string filepath1, string filepath2)
{
    try
    {
        var exampleA = File.ReadAllText(filepath1);
        var exampleB = File.ReadAllText(filepath2);

        var diff = new XmlDiff(exampleA, exampleB);

        diff.CompareDocuments(new XmlDiffOptions()
        {
            TwoWayMatch = true
        }
        );
        txtOutput.Text = diff.ToString();
        jsonViewer1.Json = diff.ToString();
    }
    catch (StackOverflowException e)
    {
        ShowException(e);
    }

}
```

El error que devuelve es este:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Ahora bien, **el error ya sé que es un bug de la librería** y el autor está trabajando en corregirlo. Sin embargo mi duda está en **¿Por qué la excepcion no es capturada por el Catch?**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya verifiqué la manera de manejo de excepciones en debug de Visual Studio y está configurado para el manejo normal por el usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de por qué puede ser esto?

Comment: desconozco la libreria.. pero por lo que comentas, puede que el error se de internamente en la libreria y no tenga un throw que haga escalar la misma? y por eso no podes agarrarla vos?

Comment: @gbianchi exacto, eso mismo, por eso el error dice "*unhandled exception*" o lo que sería el equivalente en español *excepción no controlada/manejada*. La excepción se dispara en un componente fuera del alcance del debugger. Talvés si revisas el `INNER EXCEPTION` te dé un poco más de detalle en la excepción que no pudo ser controlada.

Comment: Has intentado usar la raiz de excepciones para capturar cualquier tipo de excepción?

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar un ambos archivos XML que andas comparando, por favor?

Comment: Cuando se produce el exception que pasa si ingresas a la opcion "View Detalis ..." deberias poder ver alli el mensaje del error que aporte algo mas de datos sobre el problema. Tambien valida el InnerException este por lo general, sino es null, puede ayudar

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus comentarios. Exacto, la librería que estoy utilizando no maneja la excepcion correctamente, y mi duda era por qué yo no puedo capturarla, sino me hace el break y se sale de la app. Si le doy click en View Details no me sale nada, solo un mensaje de que no puede evaluar nada por causa del stack overflow: `Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copio y traduzco una respuesta dada a la misma pregunta en Stack Overflow en ingles [C# catch a stack overflow exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599238/579895):

A partir del CLR 2.0 una StackOverflowException solo puede ser capturada bajo las siguientes condiciones:

1. El CLR está corriendo en un entorno administrado donde el "host" especificamente permita que las excepciones por StackOverflow puedan ser manejadas
2. La excepcion stackoverflow es lanzada por el código del usuario y no debido a una situación de stack overflow real ([Referencia](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/22/when-can-you-catch-a-stackoverflowexception.aspx))

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Voy a investigar un poco mas sobre esta stack overflow exception.